# ES6 in Chrome - Babel Sourcemaps and Arrow Functions lexical scope

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, ecmascript-6, babeljs, source-maps

I have a function inside a ES6 `class`:

```
class Test {
   // Omitted code for brevity
   loadEvents() {
      $.get('/api/v1/events', (data) => {
         this.actions.setEvents(data);
      });
   }
}
```

Babel transpiles this to a different form and it generates a `_this` variable to control the lexical scope of the arrow function.

```
var _this = this;

$.get('/api/v1/events', function (data) {
   _this.actions.setEvents(data);
});
```

When i debug the ES6 class using sourcemaps in Chrome and put a breakpoint on the line where i call `this.actions.setEvents(data);` i noticed that Chrome does not "re-map" `this` to match the original ES6 code, but instead `this` points to the outer function scope and i need to use `_this` if i want to access the arrow function lexical scope, which is completely pointless. If i am using sourcemaps i would expect Chrome dev. tools to preserve the lexical scope of `this` as in my ES6 code.

Is there a way to make Chrome developer tools work as expected with sourcemaps and arrow functions?

Comment: _"this points to the outer function"_ - It's not clear to me what you mean by that. Is the value of `this` a function? _"i need to use _this if i want to access the arrow function scope"_ - What do `_this` and `this` have to do with the scope of a function?

Answer (score 6):

Well,

1. Chromium doesn't utilize the mappings from `names` currently. https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=327092
2. `this` is a special binding, so the way it's transpiled it wouldn't be possible to do that. The only thing I can think of would be transpiling it like this, but I don't know if it's viable:

   ```
   $.get('/api/v1/events', function (data) {
     this.actions.setEvents(data);
   }.bind(this));
   ```

Comment: So you are saying that a in-browser debugger like Chrome's would not be able to intercept the call for `this` in the different tools (e.g. the Watch window or Console) and re-map it to something else? i know `this` is a special value, and the actual `this` is of course not something that can be modified, but i am more talking about some advanced debugger features.

Comment: Probably technically it could, but how would it work? You've gotta be able to inspect the real value of `this`. I don't know that doing anything to obscure the values of special bindings like that is a good idea.

Comment: yeah, maybe. But again what is the point of SourceMaps if you can't debug the code in the original ES6 state? It is very confusing and  definitely a pretty big issue in my book. If i put a breakpoint in an Arrow function i need to check what is the actual _self/_this variable in the transpiled code and then i can debug properly, which seems like a tedious debugging workflow.

Comment: The point of source mapping is all of the other cases it _can_ help with. Transpiling isn't perfect. If this is too much of a problem for you, you could just not use arrow functions while you need to transpile them, or set a var like `self` in the outer scope like you might do otherwise, or look into creating or commissioning an arrow function transformer that produces output like I suggested with `bind()` (I don't know what complications there might be with that).

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [Babel arrow function transformer](https://github.com/babel/babel/blob/0b88a89b87b18bddecbd9f6eae9eaa993e86bf1e/packages/babel-plugin-transform-es2015-arrow-functions/src/index.js), it seems it already implements the bind(this) solution, which makes the debugger display the correct this.

I tested it in my chrome developer tools.